Understanding why Mobius Strip is non orientable
I am reading Algebraic Topology by Massey. The book defined Mobius Strip as follows:
Form a quotient space of $X=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2~:~x\in [-10,10],y\in (-1,1)\}$ by identifying points $(10,y)$ to $(-10,-y)$, the center line of the rectangular strip becomes a circle after identification of the two end points. We leave it to the reader to verify that if our imaginary bug started out at any point on this circle with a definite choice of orientation and carried this orientation with him around the circle once, he would come back to his initial point with his original orientation reversed. We call such a path $\textbf{orientation reversing}$ path.
I want to verify this but I am not sure how to go about this. Let $\sim $ denote the relation described above and I believe the topology on the quotient space is the topology that makes the following map continuous
$$\pi :X\to X\backslash \sim$$
where $\pi$ maps every point to the identification that contains the point. Now I take a path $p:[0,1]\to X\backslash \sim$ where $p(0)=p(1)=[(10,0)]$ and $p(t)=(1-t)p_0+tp_1$. To show the path is orientation reversing I think I just need to look at the normal vector $n_p$ at every point of $p(t)$. And show at some point $t\in [0,1]$ the vector change sign ? I do not see how the quotient topology on $X\backslash \sim$ is related to the changing of the sign at all. Am I on a completely wrong track? Thanks

What do you mean by normal vector? Normal to the circle in the Möbius strip? An abstractly-defined surface, such as $X/{\sim}$, has no normal vector field. Let's go back and decide how orientation of a surface (manifold with boundary, here) has been defined. Do you know that since the circle is orientable, the Möbius strip is orientable if and only if the normal bundle of the circle is orientable?

I did this by cutting a strip of paper, giving it a half twist, then taping the two ends together. From here I took my pen and followed the center of the strip until I got to the same point but on the opposite side. The physicality of it helped.

That definition depends on how you define orientation, but I read it as a more intuitive request of the reader, because we rarely discuss bugs on surfaces when we are talking about rigorous math. If you do have a rigorous definition of orientation, though, maybe the author does mean "verify" to mean "with a proof."

@TedShifrin The book has not defined what a normal bundle of the circle is, no smooth manifolds are mentioned at all.

Right. That's what I figured. So how is orientation defined? Since we don't have tangent spaces, we must work with $H_2(M,M-{x})\cong\Bbb Z$? How do we carry this class around a closed curve? In a rigorous multivariable calculus course, I would discuss orientations on the tangent planes to the surface along the circle ...

Are you trying to gain intuition for this, or learn how to determine this a bit more systematically?

@BrianTung I think the book wanted me to verify this intuitively but I rather learn how to determine this a bit more systemically but it seems it is hard to do that with the definitions thats provided by the book.

What is the definition? But yes, I think Massey intends this as an heuristic remark, not to be verified in a rigorous way.

@TedShifrin The book gave the definition of a Mobius strip as I stated above then defined a orientation-reversing path in a manifold as stated above. Then the book stated a connected 2-manifold is non-orientable if there is at least one orientation reversing path. The only definition given before this is a definition of n-manifold.

We can't talk about reversing orientation if we haven't defined an orientation. Massey clearly says "choice of orientation." What does that mean? (I actually never owned this book, so I am not familiar with it specifically.)

@TedShifrin I believe he meant the choice of positive direction of rotation in the plane about a point.

Where the plane must be the tangent plane to the surface, OK. So the basis ${e_1,e_2}$ at $(10,0)$ must be identified to the basis ${e_1,-e_2}$ at $(-10,0)$ because the path $(10,u)$ maps to the path $(-10,-u)$. But these bases have opposite orientation.

The Möbius strip occurs in Chapter I "Two-Dimensional Manifolds" on p.3/4. At this stage Massey does not give a formal definition of an orientation, but only gives an idea for $\mathbb R^2$, or more generally for a small region in the plane.
He works with left-hand and right-hand coordinate systems, or alternatively with the positive and negative direction of a rotation in the plane. He then considers an "intelligent bug"  who chooses an orientation at a point of the plane and carries this choice with him when moving on the plane. This transports orientations from one point to another along a path connecting the points.
The same can be done on each $2$-manifold $M$ since it is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$. Massey says that $M$ is orientable if the bug starts at any point $p \in M$  and moves along any closed path in $M$, then the chosen orientation transported along the path agrees with the orginally chosen orientation at the point.
This is just a heuristic approach, albeit a very vivid one. The formal concept of orientation is introduced much later in the book (Chapter XIV p.350 ff).
Therefore you should not be too formal when checking that the center circle is an orientation reversing path. Normal vectors are not needed; this concept is not defined by Massey (and it depends on an embedding into a higher dimensional manifold which is not needed here).
In my opinion it suffices to make a physical model by taking a long strip of paper (or better: a transparent film), giving one of the two ends a half twist and then gluing the ends. Then take a small piece of transparent film, draw on it a circle with orientation (i.e. with an arrowhead pointing in on direction) and move it once around the center circle. You will see that the arrowhead points in the other direction.
The reason for this pehonomenon is of course the half-twist before gluing: When traversing the glued ends, orientation switches. Look at the "unglued" strip and jump from one end to the other, and make the half twist with the transparent film when jumping.
